# Text Alignment in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying align my text in my table, it any bootstrap class does it?

as you can see the text it is a bit up comparing with the icon and the `<td>`

any quick solution for this?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wuuf5g87/9/

css:

```
table i {
  color: #3181cc;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e5eaee;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
<table class="table table-scroll table-striped" aurelia-table="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-4">Time</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Time of Call</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12:00:00<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>
        Call 3:00pm<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        wwwwwww
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00:00:00<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>
        Call 7:00pm<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        wwwwwww
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below css in your css:

```
.table td i {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

it will solve your problem.

**Update:**

Here is the updated CSS class that class, you are using:

```
table i {
  color: #3181cc;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e5eaee;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -5px; //add this line in your exiting class
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wuuf5g87/14/

Comment: thanks, I inserted the wrong jsfiddle, the right one is that one: jsfiddle.net/wuuf5g87/9

Comment: @Raduken Check the updated answer with updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

They just need a little margin:

```css
table i {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table table-scroll table-striped" aurelia-table="">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-4">Time</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Time of Call</th>
      <th class="col-md-4">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12:00:00<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>
        Call 3:00pm<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        wwwwwww
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00:00:00<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
      <td>
        Call 7:00pm<i class="fa fa-clock-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        wwwwwww
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, I inserted the wrong jsfiddle, the right one is that one: https://jsfiddle.net/wuuf5g87/9/